# Attribute error Cmd module

Tags: python, cmd, attributeerror

I'm trying to use cmd module of python, and I got this test code in a website
When compiling this code in python 3.2

```
import cmd
import os

class ShellEnabled(cmd.Cmd):

    last_output = ''

    def do_shell(self, line):
        "Run a shell command"
        print ("running shell command:", line)
        output = os.popen(line).read()
        print (output)
        self.last_output = output

    def do_echo(self, line):
        "Print the input, replacing '$out' with the output of the last shell command"
        # Obviously not robust
        print (line.replace('$out', self.last_output))

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShellEnabled().cmdloop()
```

I get this error for cmd module.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cmd'
```

On line 4.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and found no error... By the way, where is the function cmdloop() that you are calling?

Comment: @lowitty it is method of cmd.Cmd. on python 3.3 works fine.

Comment: @m.wasowski Thanks! Actually I tried this script and get the output: (Cmd) and no error.

Comment: So it will not work on python 3.2 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried you script with `python3.2.3` and it worked. Do you have a file named `cmd.py` in the same directory as this file is in? If you do, then `import cmd` would not import the right module. Instead, it would import `cmd.py` in the current directory.

I created a file called `cmd.py` in the directory and got the same error as you did when trying to run your script. So delete `cmd.py` that is in the current directory or name it something else if you have it there.

Answer (score -1):

I think there exists a file with name **cmd.py**. Try after removing it. It works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just a summary of the existing and accepted answer.